# Manipulate dynamic array of pointers to 2 array

Tags: c

I'm trying to init the value of the array inside the function but i'm really struggling with it.
The following code gives me a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` error.

At the end I want an array like `[piecesNumber][10][10]` where pieces number is 12.

`MAX_SIZE` is just a define = 10.

```
int main() {

    int (*pieces) [MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE] = NULL;

    createPieces(&pieces);

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        for (int x = 0; x < MAX_SIZE; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < MAX_SIZE; ++y) {
                printf("%d",pieces[i][x][y]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void createPieces(int (**pieces)[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE]){
    
    *pieces = malloc(sizeof(int[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE])*piecesNumber()); //piecesNumber = 12 

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < MAX_SIZE; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < MAX_SIZE; y++) {
                *pieces[i][x][y] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you very much for you're help I'm trying to solve this since yesterday morning :(

Comment: Yes pieces number() returns 12.

Comment: The error I get comes when I do : *pieces[i][x][y] = 1;

Comment: Any time you receive an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error -- the most likely cause is you are abusing a pointer and attempting to access a memory address outside of your programs allowable range (like down in the system-reserved memory area, etc..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by unintended grouping.  The following:

```
*pieces[i][x][y] = 1;
```

should be:

```
(*pieces)[i][x][y] = 1;
```

Without the parentheses, the `*` operator is only applied after the indexing, which clearly won't work.